# How to fetch a string between <> in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a URL link

```
Link=<http://mysample.link.com/first/12/sample?page=1234-asdf>;rel="next"
```

I want to fetch everything between <> and get the result as `http://mysample.link.com/first/12/sample?page=1234-asdf`

Currently I am using String.substring() like 
`finalString=sample.subString(sample.indexOf("<"),sample.indexOf(">"));`

but I don't think this is the best approach. Could someone please tell me how can I fetch the result string using regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a regex for that:

```
<([^>]+)>
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/lT3xS4

Comment: You have to fetch group(1) of the result match.

Comment: Thanks you very much. Also thanks for your website link

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this one: `(?<=Link=<).+?(?=>)` to only capture the actual url in the link "tag".

Answer (score 1):

The following will work for you.

```
String s = "Link=<http://mysample.link.com/first/12/sample?page=1234-asdf>;rel=\"next\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<([^>]+)>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}

// "http://mysample.link.com/first/12/sample?page=1234-asdf"
```